# Why is the output of this not what it should be?

Tags: c, floating-point, pow, exponent

So I had a assignment to calculate 10^100, had to use the pow() function in result. So here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main()
{
    long double result;
    result = pow(10, 100);
    printf("10^100 = %Lf", result);
}
```

If I assign `pow(10, 100)` to `result`, the result displayed is 100000000000000001590289110975991804683608085639452813897813275577478387721703810608. But, if I write the code like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main()
{
    printf("10^100 = %Lf", pow(10, 100));
}
```

I get what I'm supposed to get i.e. 10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.000000.

So someone please explain why this is happening and how to avoid this?

Comment: It's surprising that you get a good result at all for second version. This is undefined behaviour as you only provide a `double` parameter while `printf` expects `long double`

Comment: Which compiler, version, and switches?

Comment: Alternatively, research <tgmath.h> to use `pow()` with `long double`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that in the latter case, the compiler used *constant folding* to replace the printf with an *exact* string. But in the former case it used the *closest result presentable in long double*, and that's the best you can get.

Notice that you should use `powl`, not `pow` for the *long double result*. In the latter case it is not only *should* but **must**, as `%Lf` will expect a `long double`, not `double`  in the arguments.

To have more precise output at runtime, you need to use an arbitrary precision math library or build one yourself.

Comment: Good observation about _constant folding_ possibility.